# Questions about OSGi configuration

Tags: osgi, aem

If I configure from OSGi bundle configuration console, configuration files are stored under `/apps/system/config`.

Here are my questions:

1. Does the configuration under config folder is applied for both
   author and publish instances?
2. If yes then how will they we connected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to build a content package, containing this node, and use as required on your other instances.

**specific run mode structures as follows:**

1. **config** - for all run modes
2. **config.author** - for the author environment
3. **config.publish** - for the publish environment
4. **config.** - as appropriate

> i.e. the presence of these nodes in which environment will decide
>   their effectiveness.

From Adobe documentation **Configuration Persistence** as follows

If you change a configuration through the Web console, it is (usually) written into the repository at: /apps/{somewhere}

> By default {somewhere} is system/config so the configuration is
>   written to **/apps/system/config**

However, if you are editing a configuration which initially came from elsewhere in the repository: for example:**/libs/foo/config/someconfig**
Then the updated configuration is written under the original location; for example:**/apps/foo/config/someconfig**